# updating sql query skips indexes

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to save user search results in sql using this query.

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO search_data (SEARCH, COUNT) VALUES (?,1) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE COUNT = COUNT + 1";
```

My database has 3 columns. ID, SEARCH and COUNT.

```
ID - auto increment, unique, primary.
SEARCH - unique.
COUNT - int.
```

The problem here is when updating a data it skips a index value. For eg.

```
search 1 - hii
search 2 - hello
search 3 - hii
search 4 - skipping index.
```

instead of giving the desired result (ID - 1,2,3) it gives (ID - 1,2,4)

Look at this photo for better clarity.

[image]

Comment: An INSERT was attempted, so the current auto_increment value had to be incremented for that. There is nothing actually wrong here, other than your "desired result", because there is absolutely no good reason whatsoever, why one would insist on that to begin with. The _only_ purpose of an auto-increment ID is to identify the record, nothing else. Especially not to "look pretty" by not having any holes in the sequence.

Comment: Agreed, this is only a problem in your imagination. Is it actually causing you any practical difficulty in your data or application?

Comment: So how can we go solving about this? i want the ID to be sequential.

Comment: For what purpose? What is the advantage of having sequential IDs? They are just an abitrary value, with no other meaning than to uniquely identify the row they are on. The fact mysql creates them by incrementing numbers one after another is merely coincidental. It could just as easily assign random numbers, or use GUIDs or something like that.

Comment: Again, there's nothing to solve here, there isn't a problem. If you're attempting to use these IDs for some other purpose than their designed one, then that is solved by ceasing to do that. You can maybe use another column in your table for whatever your purpose is, or perhaps (depending on the use case) generating sequential numbers on-demand in a SELECT query using ROW_NUMBER.

Comment: Haven't thought about it like that, thanks man.